# Ruby - rails - jquery autocomplete parse json

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is this a correct way to parse map json returned to a ajax autocomplete call? 
I was expecting that jQuery understands json responce and will not require any additional effort in the script to list autocomplete items.

json -

```
[{"issue":"Item returned"}]
```

JS -

```
$("#term").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
                url: '/issue/issue_type',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { issue_code : $("#term").val() },
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>' },
                success: function(data) { response($.map(data.issue, function(issue){
                return {
                value: data.issue
                }
                } )); }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui){ 
        //
                }
        });
        });
```

Tried `success: function(data) { response(data); }`. didn't work either.

Controller -

```
def issue_type
        @c = Codes.select("issue").where("codes.issue LIKE :i",{:i => "#{params[:posted_code]}%"})
        puts @c.to_json
        respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json=> @c.to_json }
        format.js
        end
        return @c.to_json
        end
```

Comment: You are missing a quote here: `url: '/issue/issue_type,`. It should be: `url: '/issue/issue_type',`

Comment: @Mischa - Ohh that was just a typo in posting code here. I do get ajax json response, but doesn't get listed in autocomplete list.

Comment: well what does your autocomplete html look like? Your select: function... is where the response would be appended to the autocomplete list, if thats blank then your results are not going to be displayed

Comment: @Mike - It is a text field. I am updating my question with my controller.

Comment: When you start typing into the text field does the javascript console in firebug show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you are missing is the javasscript to append the results returned from your controller to the drop down list

example taken from JqueryUI; http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
 #function to write 'selected: <selection>' in demo
function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }
 #when user selects from drop down passes selected value to log function
select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },




  # i think this is CSS to make the drop down list appear/disappear
open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        }, 

 close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
```

this stuff is either blank or missing. The log function isnt a requirement but on select something should happen with javascript to make the selection appear in the text field.

Also it looks like your data is not formated right,

```
data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
```

success doesnt look right either. I would just copy and paste the view source from, http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp and customize it to fit your application.